# mutated 'this' in javascript super call, how to deal with?

Tags: javascript, superclass, super

Sorry if it's hard to explain. 
Suppose class Y extends class Z, and class X extends class Y

The thing is if a class doesn't have a method, it calls it's super class, so far so good.

`X.prototype.v = function{return this.getV();} //getV() doesn't exist in class X`

since class X extends class Y and getV() exist in class Y, the call goes here:

```
Y.prototype.getV = function{return this.parent().getV()+1}
```

the working function parent() returns an instance of it's super class. Suppose z also has a method getV, which returns a real int value.

```
Z.prototype.getV = function{return 1}
```

So the function getV() in class Y is mean to return the getV value from Z plus 1, and send it to the lowest class X.

Most wired part is here. As long as the method getV is called from X.v(), 'this' in y.getV() refer to X, not Y!

so the function getV() in Y becomes X.parent().getV()+1, and I get 'maximum call stack size exceeded'

A stupid but extremely effective way to solve this, is to write

```
this.parent().parent().getV()+1
```

double parents make the sender Z not y, then it returns 2 when calling X.getV()

It's stupid because if the caller is Y itself, like Y.getV(), I think then 'this' correctly means Y here, then there're too many parent() calls, leading it to undefined.

Some thoughts like we can get rid of 'this', and use another way to get current class. Less desirable way might be keeping track of all functions for all classes, and set the correct number of parent(). I believe there's more. However, none of them was tested out yet.

A minimal code example, taken from the pieces of code above, can be:

```
class Z{

}
class Y extends Z{

}
class X extends Y{

}

X.prototype.v = function{
    return this.getV();
}

Y.prototype.getV = function{
    return this.parent().getV()+1;
}

Z.prototype.getV = function{
    return 1;
}

var x = new X();
console.log(x.v());
```

Comment: This is somewhat confusing, as ES2015 introduces both classes and `super`, but you seem to be using prototyping, and expecting it to behave like classical OOP. It seems the issue is scope, and how the `this` value of a function is set based on execution context, but it's not easy to grok ?

Comment: Could you post a minimal code example? It's hard to see what's going on from your description.

Comment: minimal code example added, thanks.

Comment: Please show us your implementation of `parent`. Most likely that's where the problem lies, because if you really mean "prototype chain parent" then it doesn't make sense to use in overrideable methods.

Comment: parent() of X returns new Y, parent() of Y returns new Z. It's that simple, like I said, manually controlling the number of parent() call makes everything work (in one single case).

Comment: Why do you think you need that `parent` method at all? It seems pretty useless.

Comment: What am I supposed to use? A prototype call returns an uninstantiated SAME class. Although an alternative way doesn't give answer for the question I asked, I'd still like to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` refers to the context in which a function is called, or in more practical terms: it refers to the object that appears before the dot in the call. When you call `abc.def()`, then `this` in `def` will be the same as `abc`.

So the easiest might be to change this:

```
X.prototype.v = function{return this.getV();}
```

to:

```
X.prototype.v = function{return this.parent().getV();}
```

This makes the `this` for Y to be the above `this.parent()`. This way you don't have to change your original call.

But if you want to keep the flexibility to define *X.prototype.getV*, then it is probably better to define it immediately, and instead of the above change, do this:

```
X.prototype.v = function{return this.getV();}
X.prototype.getV = function{return this.parent().getV();}
```

#### Alternative: Use apply/call

You could pass an explicit reference to what the target function should use as `this`, using the [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) method (or `call` which is anther flavour of the same):

```
X.prototype.v = function{return this.getV.apply(this.parent(), arguments);}
```

#### Test if prototype has defined own method:

You could use [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty):

```
X.prototype.v = function{
    var nextThis = X.prototype.hasOwnProperty('getV') ? this : this.parent();
    return this.getV.apply(nextThis, arguments);
}
```

`

Comment: "this refers to the context of the caller", thanks for the clue. Since the system know which class the function being executed belongs to, isn't there really a way to reveal it? I think I need that maximum flexibility.

Comment: @user3352539: You need to derive the "parent method" from the current function, not from the value of `this`. Btw, `super` does it for you automatically in ES6.

Comment: Is that the only way? Cause I have to know the exact inheritance, with possibly 0 parent() call needed. I prefer making it more dynamic.

Comment: I added an alternative, making use of `apply`: that really fixes what `this` should be for the target function, wherever it may be defined.

Comment: You can see if prototype has defined a certain method or not with `hasOwnProperty`. Updated answer.

Comment: This is an awful solution. No, you cannot make this dynamic depending on `this`, it will *always* fail in some case. You need to resolve the parent statically. See Oriols answer on how to do that.

Comment: The last solution added, X.prototype.hasOwnProperty('getV') works dynamically. We can even use a while loop to find the far parent node.

Comment: @user3352539: That doesn't work for subclasses of `X`. And how would `Y.prototype.getV` look like in that solution?

Comment: X is like the leaf of the structure, I only mentioned the need to track parent class. The other way is much harder, Imagine tracking one subclass while multiple subclasses extends to a same parent class. Back to this question, both X.prototype.getV and Y.prototype.getV look like in the solution, depending on the properties the child class contains.

Answer (score 1):

If you use ES6 class syntax, you should use `super`:

```
class Z {
  getV() {
    return 1;
  }
}
class Y extends Z {
  getV() {
    return super.getV() + 1;
  }
}
class X extends Y {
  v() {
    return super.getV(); // or this.getV();
  }
}
new Z().getV(); // 1
new Y().getV(); // 2
new X().getV(); // 2
new X().v();    // 2
```

In ES5, I would use something like

```
function extend(f1, f2) {
  f1.prototype = Object.create(f2.prototype);
  f1.prototype.constructor = f1;
  f1.super = f2.prototype;
}
function Z(){}
Z.prototype.getV = function() {
  return 1;
};
function Y(){}
extend(Y, Z);
Y.prototype.getV = function() {
  return Y.super.getV.call(this) + 1;
};
function X(){}
extend(X, Y);
X.prototype.v = Y.prototype.getV;
new Z().getV(); // 1
new Y().getV(); // 2
new X().getV(); // 2
new X().v();    // 2
```

Comment: In class `X`, you could even use `this` with the same result.